# How to add click event to ASP.NET button created in other class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class that creates a textbox and a button with specific attributes.
The task of the button is to set the textbox text to a default value.

My problem is that I add

```
myButton.Click += myButton_Click

(also tried myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click))

protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Text = "foo";
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried to add the event in the class itself and in the webpage I want to use these elements, but when I click the button nothing happens.

What could be the problem? Is the method inaccessible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have registered the event on your form in the aspx file:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
```

Comment: textbox and button are created programmatically, so there is no entry in the aspx file

Comment: when adding the control programmatically, the control also needs to be added to the parent container with `Panel1.Controls.Add(myButton)`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/kyt0fzt1%28v%3dvs.100%29